# Using the ABSPATH constant - What files need to be loaded before use?

Tags: constants

I need to make use of the ABSPATH constant but need to know what WP files I need to include so I can make use of it.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is defined at the very [start of `wp-load.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-load.php).

However it's value is very primitive - only a path to where file is located, which you could easily get without bothering with including it.