# WordPress upload file - get path to WordPress installation

Tags: uploads

I'm trying to make a script that uploads a file to a specific folder in the wordpress installation.

Basically I want to upload to /uploads. However, in order to do this I need to know the server path for the WordPress installation.

How can I get this?

Comment: Related: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/12339/getting-path-to-uploaded-attachment-image-after-upload

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [wp_upload_dir()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_upload_dir) for path to uploads, and use [get_bloginfo()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_bloginfo) to get paths to the WP location

Answer (score 2):

You can retrieve the path where Wordpress has been installed to from the `ABSPATH` constant.

It should be available in your plugin/theme code, it is defined at the very [start of `wp-load.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1/wp-load.php).

See also: **[Using the ABSPATH constant - What files need to be loaded before use?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/12047/178)**